# Javascript detect click but no function

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm setting up an audio player in javascript, however when I want to detect `onclick` by user, the code breaks and everything results in `Loading...` messages and no sound on the actual player.

This is the code:

```
    /*else if (document.getElementById("batar-btn").onclick = function())
    {
        player.src = 'http://live.shockradio.co.uk/ob';
    }*/
```

I want for the stream address to change after the page loads for the user, AND the button with `batar-btn` ID is clicked. **How can I do this similarly with the above code?**

```
player = document.createElement("audio");
if (typeof player.canPlayType === "function" && player.canPlayType("audio/mpeg") !== "")
{
    backend = 'html';
    var format = "mp3";
    player = new Audio();
    if (isMobile)
    {
        $('#muteIcon').css('display', 'none');
        $('#playIcon').css('display', 'inline-block');
        if (player.canPlayType("audio/mp4; codecs=\"mp4a.40.5\"") !== "")
        {
            player.src = 'http://live.shockradio.co.uk/mobile';
        }
        else
        {
            player.src = 'http://live.shockradio.co.uk/mp3';
        }
    }
    /*else if (document.getElementById("batar-btn").onclick = function())
    {
        player.src = 'http://live.shockradio.co.uk/ob';
    }*/
    else
    {
        player.src = 'http://live.shockradio.co.uk/mp3';
    }
    player.mozAudioChannelType = 'content';
    player.addEventListener("playing", showStopIcon, false);
    player.addEventListener("pause", showPlayIcon, false);
    player.addEventListener("ended", showPlayIcon, false);
    player.load();
    player.play();
}
else
{
    backend = 'flash';
    swfobject.embedSWF('swf/player.swf', 'flashPlayer', '1', '1', '10');
    document.title = '\u25b6 Shock Radio Player';
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Player', 'Play']);
}
```

Comment: onclick = function()) <--  --> onclick = function()

Answer (score 0):

Should check is it function like this:

```
else if (typeof document.getElementById("batar-btn").onclick === 'function')
{
    player.src = 'http://live.shockradio.co.uk/ob';
}
```